# How to save a polygon shape in LibreOffice Writer's Contour Editor?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I'm presently in the Contour Editor, where I've successfully created a polygon shape around my image, by adding one point after the other. Now I have a shape that is satisfactory, but pressing escape will erase it, and the "Apply" button is greyed out. How do I save the polygon contour? Is it a keyboard shortcut thing?

[image: contour_editor]

By the way, moving my cursor around results in the present polygon shape point following it, because I've not yet escaped the polygon editing, not knowing how to.

Comment: What verssion of LibreOffice are you using? What happens if you click the close button? Do you see the dialog button to save?

Comment: What happens when you click on the title bar? Does that enable the apply button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the contour the way you want it, double-click. The Apply button should then be active. Clicking Apply will then apply the contour to the image in your document.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concise answer! I had figured it out, but forgot to come back a write it down. +1